# download the csv file from Hadoop Hue returns unreadable code

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, hue

I use the Apache Hue (User interface) to interact with Hadoop and Hive.

I saved the result of a hive query in a HDFS directory. (The result set is really large)

Then, I downloaded the result file with hue file browser.

Every thing looks fine, but as I opened the csv file, I found the separator is some unreadable code, like this:

[image]

How can I solve the separator problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOH** (start of heading) or its [Seq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation) equivalent <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> is the default field delimiter used by Hive. And all the `\N` represent NULL.

Solution to this depends on the version of Hive used

> As of Hive 0.11.0 the separator used can be specified; in earlier
>   versions it was always the ^A character (\001). However, custom
>   separators are only supported for LOCAL writes in Hive versions 0.11.0
>   to 1.1.0 – this bug is fixed in version 1.2.0

If using Hive >= 1.2.0, you can specify the `FIELDS TERMINATED BY` clause in your `INSERT OVERWRITE` statements to choose your delimiter.

```
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY hdfs_directory SELECT statement ... 
  ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ...
```

Refer [HIVE-3682](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-3682) and [HIVE-5672](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-5672).

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest you replace the noisy 'SOH' by "," and remove the '\N' directly.

If you use python, it's just a one-liner:

`pd.read_csv("your_file.csv", sep="\001", na_values='\N']).to_csv("your_new_file.csv")`